# JQuery click trigger fires twice in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

This is happening only in IE8. It works in Firefox, chrome and IE11

When I press enter in the input box the addToCart method is being called twice. But if I click on the button it is called only once. Pls help.

The validateInput method gets called only once on pressing enter.

I tried triggerHandler, but it fires addToCart on the wrong (first) element. Off/on , unbind/bind didn't help.

Html:

```
<input id="quantity_225300" class="quantity numberinput" type="number">
<label class="sr-only" for="quantity_225300">Label Text</label>
<button id="addBtn_225300" class="addToCartBtn btn btn-mini" style="vertical-align: top;" disabled="">Add</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".addToCartBtn", addToCart);
  $(document).on("blur", "input.quantity", validateInput);
  $(document).on("keydown", "input.quantity", checkAndSubmitForEnterKey);
});

function checkAndSubmitForEnterKey(event){
var index = $(this).attr('id').lastIndexOf("_");
var skunum = $(this).attr('id')
        .substr(index + 1, $(this).attr('id').length);
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
    $(this).trigger("blur");
    $('#addBtn_'+skunum).trigger("click");
 }  
}

var addToCart = function() {
log.debug("add to cart");
}

var validateInput = function() {
 log.debug("validated");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding event.preventDefault solved it.

```
if (event.keyCode == '13') {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).trigger("blur");
   $('#addBtn_'+skunum).trigger("click");
 }  
}
```

Comment: I just came across this, do you know why this is the case?

Comment: I think the blur() on the element and triggering again is the reason. I don't have the same codebase anymore. So I cant really test. Its just a guess.